# Android material TabLayout TabItem doesn't show text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, material-components-android

I want to set up a TabLayout. When I add TabItems inside of XML or programatically, they occupy space and can be clicked, yet their text is not displayed. When I access their text programatically inside of OnTabSelectedListener via tab.getText(), it's there.
The same happened, when I wanted to use the pager.
I know, that

> TabItem is not actually added to TabLayout, it is just a dummy which
> allows setting of a tab items's text, icon and custom layout

but i don't know how to show its text on the screen.
AndroidStudio's design shows the layout as intended.
I write my app in Java.

.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorSurfaceElevation1dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_dayTabItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Day"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_myExercisesTabItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Exercises"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_exerciseTabItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exercises"/>

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

How it looks in AndroidStudio: 
[How it looks in AndroidStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJIr0.png)

How it looks in the app: 
[How it looks in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvewJ.png)

please help material is driving me crazy

Comment: Add these two to your xml **app:tabTextColor ="@color/white"
       app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"** in TabsLayout view

Comment: @SarahKhan sadly, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This can be solve programmatically

**Step 1** Create `FragmentStateAdapter` adapter class

```java
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public TabAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new DayFragment();
            case 1:
                return new MyExerciseFragment();
            default:
                return new ExerciseFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**Step 2** Create a method in your `activity` or `fragment` class to set tabs using `TabLayoutMediator` and call the method in `onCreate` method

```java
void setupTabLayout() {
        ViewPager2 viewPager = binding.exerciseMenuViewPager;
        
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = binding.exerciseMenuTabLayout;

        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, (tab, position) -> {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tab.setText("Day");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tab.setText("My Exercise");
                    break;
                default:
                    tab.setText("Exercise");
            }
        }).attach();
    }
```

This is how your activity class will look like

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private TabAdapter tabAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(this);

        setupTabLayout();
    }

    void setupTabLayout() {}
}
```

**NOTE:** To use *ViewBinding* add this code to your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
android{
    
    ...
     buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    ...
}
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/exercise_menu_tabLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Final results](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47930771/108611496-ee1cea00-73d6-11eb-9dab-e6cfd78e48b9.png)

***PS:*** You need to create these fragment classes `DayFragment.java`, `MyExerciseFragment.java`and `ExerciseFragment`.

Comment: Your answer probably works, but binding doesn't see views from outside the MainActivity.
I don't really want to use fragments, because i already wrote the whole backend for changing RecyclerViews, so I made my own TabLayout with TextViews and a drawable with a line on the bottom. Works the same, and only misses the moving line animation. Thanks for your time tho

Comment: When you enable `view binding` all layout files generate their own binding classes. [Read more here.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#java)

Answer (score 0):

Because I didn't want to use pager with fragments, and I couldn't get TabLayout to work, I made my own TabLayout. 
I used LinearLayout with TextViews and just made a drawable with a line at the bottom and appropriate backgroundColor. It works flawlessly, and the only thing missing is the animation for line movement. 
After each click, look of the previously selected textView is restored, and the new one is changed.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_dayTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Day"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="@color/colorSurfaceElevation1dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_myExercisesTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Exercises"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:background="@drawable/back_line_bottom"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_menu_exerciseTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exercises"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:background="@color/colorSurfaceElevation1dp"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"/>
```

back_line_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorSurfaceElevation1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

background changing:

```
public void changeTypeVisually(int tabId) {
    //  Resets the background
    switch(currentTabId) {
        case 0:
            myExercisesTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSurfaceElevation1dp));
            myExercisesTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            break;
        case 1:
            dayTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSurfaceElevation1dp));
            dayTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            break;
        case 2:
            exerciseTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSurfaceElevation1dp));
            exerciseTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
            break;
    }

    //  Adds the underline
    switch(tabId) {
        case 0:
            myExercisesTextView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_line_bottom));
            myExercisesTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            break;
        case 1:
            dayTextView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_line_bottom));
            dayTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            break;
        case 2:
            exerciseTextView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_line_bottom));
            exerciseTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            break;
    }
    currentTabId = tabId;
}
```